# Why while loop doesn't loop after first run? While loop can't read new value of variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, while-loop, null

I'm new to Python, and wondering why this might of occurred.
Here's the code:

```
import turtle


What_Calculate = turtle.numinput("Area of Different Shapes Calculator", "Type 1 to calculate the area of a square, Type 2 to calulate the area of a rectangle, Type 3 to calculate the area if a triangle, Type 4 to calulate the area of a circle, or click [q] to quit:")

while What_Calculate !="q":

    if What_Calculate == 1:
        Length_Square = eval(input("What is the length of the square?:"))
        Area_Squ = Length_Square * Length_Square
        print("The area of the square is ", Area_Squ, ".")
        What_Calculate = input("Click another number or click [q] to exit:")

    elif What_Calculate == 2:
        Length_1 = eval(input("What is the first length?:"))
        Length_2 = eval(input("What is the second length?:"))
        Area_Rec = Length_1 * Length_2
        print("The area of the rectangle is ", Area_Rec, ".")
        What_Calculate = input("Click another number or click [q] to exit:")

    elif What_Calculate == 3:
        Length = eval(input("What is the length?:"))
        Height = eval(input("What is the height?:"))
        Area = Length * Height / 2
        print("The area of the triangle is", Area)
        What_Calculate = input("Click another number or click [q] to exit:")

    elif What_Calculate == 4:
        Diameter = eval(input("What's the diameter of the circle?:"))
        Radius = Diameter / 2
        Pie = 3.14
        Area = Pie * Radius * Radius
        print("The area of the circle is ", Area, ".")
        What_Calculate = input("Click another number or click [q] to exit:")
```

Here's the problem:
After the user inputs which calculator they want to use, the code works until after the answer is given.
At `What_Calculate = input("Click another number or click [q] to exit:")`, typing `q` to exit works perfectly, but `1`-`4` doesn't work at all. If I'm not wrong shouldn't the `while` loop in this scenario, loop until `What_Calculate` is null?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `What_Calculate = input("Click another number or click [q] to exit:")` returns a string, which ALWAYS fails in the if/elif/elif/elif. Because it is a string and not a number, `"1" != 1`. The easiest way to do it that I could see is to add

```
try:
    What_Calculate = int(What_Calculate)
except ValueError:
    #Some code to handle what happens if What_Calculate cannot be turned into an int.
```

to the beginning of the while loop. Having this contained in a try/except loop allows you to detect if the user input something that is not an integer and is not the letter 'q'.

Comment: @martineau true. Fixed.

Comment: Thank You! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

[input()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) returns a string... You're checking for an int

Answer (score 0):

The input() functions returns a string, and since all of your comparisons in the loop are numbers it will loop forever after the first time through. You should not be using `What_Calculate` as both an int and a string - my suggestion (trying to change as little of the code as possible) would be to change your comparisons from `if What_Calculate == 1:` to `if What_Calculate == "1":` and so on, then change your `turtle.numinput` call to ask for a string input instead of a number.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!